# CSS/SVG Create Spiral

Tags: css, svg

### I am looking for a way of creating a "Spiral" in CSS.

Here is an image to make it a bit more clear what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Spiral]

> So a partial circle with an outline that gets bigger.

- *Ideally I want to be able to set the length of the Spiral. (from (0) to 360°)*
- *Also it would be nice to place a cricle at the end (just like in my sample)*

---

Here is a codesnippet of what I came up so far.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  
  border-top: 30px solid #fd0;
  border-right: 40px solid #fa0;
  border-bottom: 60px solid #f50;
  border-left: 0 solid blue;

  border-radius: 50%;
  
  position: relative;
}
div::after { /* kreis */
  content: "";
  position: absolute; top: 80%; left: 8%;
  width: 90px; height: 90px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
div::before { /* hide the stuff that is too much. */
  content: "";
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0;
  width: 50px; height: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**I would also accept an svg way of doing this.**

Comment: By 0-360 do you mean "any angle between 0 and 360"?

Answer (score 3):

this what i came up with some tweaking Css and html i guess it similar to the image [DEMO](http://codepen.io/CY5/pen/KrmBXo) Not tested on IE not sure whether responsive it is

```css
.spiral{
  background-color:black;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.spiral:before{
    content: '';
    width: 27px;
    height: 43px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-top-right-radius: 144px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 61px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 88px;
    left: 53px;
    top: 25px;
}
.spiral:after{
    content: '';
    width: 68px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
    top: -11px;
    transform: rotateZ(200deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="spiral"></div>
```

Comment: That's not to bad.